# android resize drawable layer-list

Tags: java, android

Hi I have looked at all other solutions and questions on SO, and none have managed to help me. I am trying to resize 2 images for a layer-list that acts as a splash screen. I have tried both alternatives below and neither work - set Size and ScaleWidth.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/couple"
            android:scaleHeight="50%"
            android:scaleWidth="50%"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/blessd"
            android:width="10dp"
            android:height="10dp"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```